# Import rows from delimited file (.cvs) into MS-Access table

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba, ado

**System background:** I am working in Access 2010 with user interface and a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 back-end where the database is stored.

**Problem background:** A machine in my lab outputs results in the form of .csv files. These files are placed in a folder on the server.  Currently, results are entered manually into the database.  The goal is to have a program in access (VBA) that reads in the data in the files row by row and inserts each row of the file into a specific table in the database.  I was instructed to us ADO objects to accomplish this.

**Progress:** My issue lies with trying to read in each row of the the delimited file.  I was given a reference website http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx but when I tried implementing the example under the subtitle *So How Do I Use ADO to Query a Text File?* and I get quite a few errors insisting methods were not found specifically at connection.Open. I want to obtain the values at each row and store them into temporary variables to pass to a stored procedure.  the stored procedure is already created and the process to insert the new record is already created.

**Sidenote on code:** The code is a lower level function meaning it does not read in all the .csv files in the folder at one time.  The function is given a file name by a higher level function and from that file name the function will read in each row from the specified file and store it in the table "tblICPMS".  Here is a sample of what the .cvs file looks like when opened in excel [image]

Here is my code:

```vb
Public Function ImportICPMS(ThisFileName As String, ThisQueueID As Long, BatchID
As Long, InstrumentName As String, TechId As Long)
On Error GoTo HandleError

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H0001

Dim obj_fso As Object
Dim objconnection As connection
Dim objRecordset As Recordset
Dim strpathtotextfile As String

'test if file exists (newpath is a public path to folder)'
Set obj_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If obj_fso.FileExists(NewPath & "\" & ThisFileName) Then
Else
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1000, "MyProjectName.MyObjectName", "file " & ThisFileName & " for " & InstrumentName & " not found" 'if false error is raised
End If

Set objconnection = CreateObject("ADODB.connection") 'create ADO objects'
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

strpathtotextfile = NewPath & "\" 'path to folder where file resides'

objconnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=strpathtotextfile;Extended Properties=;HDR = YES;FMT = Delimited"

objrecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM " & ThisFileName,objconnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Do Until objRecordset.EOF

'I do not know what Wscript.Echo means but I want to save the acquired values into
 temp variables to pass them to a stored procedure that inserts them into the table'

Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("Sample Name")
Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("Date and Time Acquired")
Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("Element Full Name")
Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("Concentration")
Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("Units")

'code to insert rows into table would probably go here'
'code to clear out local objects would go here'

objRecordset.MoveNext

Loop
objRecordset.Close
objconnection.Close
```

I did not include the rest of the code nor the stored procedure but I can if you anyone wants to see them.  I wanted to just focus my inserted code on the part I was working on.

Comment: Also Const adCmdText = &H0001 keeps automatically changing to Const adCmdText = &H1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue with methods not existing may be that it's not properly opening the CSV using that provider.
To my knowledge, SQLOLEDB.1 doesn't have this text reader functionality.

Try this, change:

```
objconnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=strpathtotextfile;Extended Properties=;HDR = YES;FMT = Delimited"
```

To this,

```
objconnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=strpathtotextfile;Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""
```

Update: noticed an issue with declarations:

```
Dim objconnection As connection
Dim objRecordset As Recordset
```

Should work as,

```
Dim objconnection As Object
Dim objRecordset As Object
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I switched it and still received a a compiling error "method or data member not found" with connection.open highlighted

Comment: I corrected my answer as I noticed the extended properties didn't have text and note the double quotes

Comment: There was still an issue with objconnection.Open, do you know if object.open is a method that can be used in VBA?

Comment: Yes you can.  The reference you are using is one I have went back to for years.  What is the latest error you get?  ** But I just noticed an issue where it's declared and will update answer.  My theory is it doesn't have the open method as it's using a DAO Connection (older than ADO, and it opens differently - less functionality)

Comment: Could the issue be caused by the .csv files being stored in MS Excel comma seperated values file and Extended Properties=""Text would be different?

Comment: The last update fixed the problem! Thank you! But now I have a new error at the first Wscript stating that the variable is not defined?

Comment: Those echoes are meant to go to a console window from VBScript.  In your case, change wscript.echo to debug.print (their example code is just displaying the values for testing)  and you won't need the .Item property.  `debug.print objRecordset.Fields("Sample Name").value`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55919/discussion-between-victoriajay-and-jimmy-smith).

Answer (score 0):

This procedure is written using Delphi XE2 
It reads cvs fields and put its into ADO Table

```
procedure addRowsFromCVS(cvsFileName : string; tblDocumentiRighe: TADOTable);

var
  cvsFileToImport   : TStringlist;
  rowCount          : integer;
  fieldCount        : integer;
  fields            : TStrings;
  fieldValues       : TStrings;

  start             : integer;
  currentFieldName  : string;
  currentFieldValue : string;

begin
  // create memory string list
  cvsFileToImport := TStringlist.create;
  fields          := TStringlist.create;
  fieldValues     := TStringlist.create;

  // load rows from file
  cvsFileToImport.loadFromFile(cvsFileName);

  // split fields row
  split(';', cvsFileToImport[0], fields);

  // first field
  start := 0;

  // for all the rows
  for rowCount := 1 to cvsFileToImport.count - 1 do begin
    // start insert
    tblDocumentiRighe.insert;

    // get field values
    split(';', cvsFileToImport[rowCount], fieldValues);

    // ...
    for fieldCount := start to fieldValues.count - 1 do begin
      currentFieldName  := fields     [fieldCount];
      currentFieldValue := fieldValues[fieldCount];

      if currentFieldValue <> '' then begin
        tblDocumentiRighe.fieldByName(currentFieldName).asString := currentFieldValue;
      end;
    end;

    // post record
    tblDocumentiRighe.post;
  end;

  // free
  fieldValues    .free;
  fields         .free;
  cvsFileToImport.free;
end;
```